# map function python3 to get message length

Tags: python-3.x

I was learning the map function, 
I was trying to get the message length by using map().
my code is

```
messages['length'] = messages['message'].map(lambda text: len(text))
```

But I am not sure since I read the map ducument map(functions, list)
The code above, should I include the list?

Thanks guys

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Why don't you just do `messages['length'] = len(messages['message'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` is a function, and not a method. That means `some_object.map(some_function)` isn't valid syntax.

The proper call would be:

```
messages['length'] = map(len, messages['message'])
```